# Azure Function - HTTP trigger request length exceeded

Tags: azure, http, post, azure-functions, limit

I am creating a small **azure function - HTTP trigger** that is hosted on the Azure Cloud. Its main function is to simply receive post requests with a CSV file as payload.

However, some of the files that are posted are larger than 100mb, which results in the following exception:

> "Exception while executing function -> Exception binding parameter 'req' -> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (104857600) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

I have tried to google my way and based on the azure function documentation
from Microsoft: ["functions-bindings-http-webhook"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#limits)

it was stated that

> The HTTP request length is limited to 100 MB (104,857,600 bytes), and the URL length is limited to 4 KB (4,096 bytes). These limits are specified by the httpRuntime element of the runtime's **Web.config** file.

Yet, I am unable to actually locate the **Web.config** within my solution, so I expect this is not really applicable or am I just totally off here?

The project is generated from Visual Studio with the following related dependencies and extensions:

> - Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions (1.0.24)
> - Azure Functions and Web jobs Tools (15.10.2046.0)

Are there any ways to increase the maximum message size limit for the received requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [App Service editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings) work for you?

However, I believe this approach is risky.  In case of networking issues you can easily receive a timeout.

I would recommend that you upload your CSVs in a blob storage, and create a blob trigger for your function.